# DAX Calculation with Datesbetween Ignores all Datefilters

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I am starting with DAX.

I have a standard date table and a table with sales. When I try to show the running total with the below formula the month filter is ignored, as shown:

[image: Running Total for previous year without monthly filter]

The formula is:

```
Prov YTD VJ 2:=CALCULATE(FIRMPROV[SumProv];
All(Kalender[Jahr]);
DATESBETWEEN(Kalender[Datum];
Min(START_YTD[start_ytd]);
MIN(END_YTD[end_ytd])))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to calculate running totals is by using the FILTER and EARLIER functions, but a prerequisite to that is that you need to create a Month Number column (ie. Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3, etc.)

Then, you can use the following DAX:

```
CALCULATE(SUM([SumProv]),ALL(FirmProv),FILTER(FirmProv,[Month Number]<=EARLIER([Month Number])))
```

EARLIER basically is DAX's way of interpreting the current row. You're telling DAX to sum ALL of the rows in the FirmProv table where the month number is less than or equal to the current row (AKA running total).

Here's the result (note the numbers aren't exactly like yours, I just quickly mocked it up to show the example):

[image]